# Гиперссылка в слово вставляется не полностью Python aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

`await message.answer(f'Ваш ID - {message.chat.id}\nК оплате - {sum}₽\n[Ссылка для оплаты](yoomoney.ru/quickpay/confirm.xml?receiver=4100117299034077&quickpay-form=shop&targets=123&paymentType=SB&sum=149)', parse_mode='Markdown', reply_markup=k.buy1)`

При нажатие на слово выдается ссылка до '?' (yoomoney.ru/quickpay/confirm.xml)
Как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, Вы забыли указать протокол в ссылке:

Вместо: `yoomoney.ru/...` используйте `https://yoomoney.ru/...`

Как альтернативу, Вы можете использовать HTML-разметку:

```py
await message.answer(
f'Ваш ID - {message.chat.id}\nК оплате - {sum}₽\n<a href="https://yoomoney.ru/quickpay/confirm.xml?receiver=4100117299034077&quickpay-form=shop&targets=123&paymentType=SB&sum=149">Ссылка для оплаты</a>',
parse_mode='HTML',
reply_markup=k.buy1
)
```